# Fields Having Algebraic Numbers as Subfield

Tags: complex-analysis, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, transcendental-numbers

In the following text, we call a power series $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}c_nz^n$ **rational** if it satisfies $\forall n, c_n \in \Bbb{Q}(i)$ and **finite** if it is a polynomial.

Let $\Bbb{A}$ be the set of complex zeropoints of all rational finite series (which is equivalent to all complex algebraic numbers), $\Bbb{A}^\omega$ be the set of complex zeropoints of all rational series that have infinite convergence radius, $\Bbb{A}^\infty$ be the set of complex zeropoints of all rational series that have non-zero convergence radius.

It is easy to show that $\Bbb{A} \subseteq \Bbb{A}^\omega \subseteq \Bbb{A}^\infty \subseteq \Bbb{C}$ and $\Bbb{A}$ is countable, so what about the size of $\Bbb{A}^\omega$ and $\Bbb{A}^\infty$? $\Bbb{A}$ is obviously a proper subset of $\Bbb{A}^\omega$ because $\ln 2$ is in the latter not the former, but the relation between $\Bbb{A}^\omega$ and $\Bbb{A}^\infty$, $\Bbb{A}^\infty$ and $\Bbb{C}$ is not clear for me:

For the first pair, I suspect that $\Bbb{A}^\omega = \Bbb{A}^\infty$ or weaker $\operatorname{Gal}(\operatorname{Frac}(\Bbb{A}^\infty) / \operatorname{Frac}(\Bbb{A}^\omega))$ is finite/countable but I have no reason -- it is so hard to determine if a given number is in $\Bbb{A}^\omega$.

For the second pair, I suspect that $\Bbb{A}^\infty$ is a proper subset of $\Bbb{C}$ because I think numbers in $\Bbb{A}^\infty$ is computable but there are uncomputable numbers in $\Bbb{C}$. However, I don't know much about computation and I hope someome would correct my fault.

**Edit**: Now that computable numbers are countable, I tend to conjecture that $\Bbb{A}^\infty = \Bbb{C}$, but I can not even prove that $\Bbb{A}^\omega$ is uncountable.

Comment: Why do you think that numbers in $\Bbb{A}^\infty$ are computable or even that this set is countable?

Comment: @JCAA In fact, I'm now considering it uncomputable because calculating a real number that a given rational sequence converges to is seemingly uncomputable.

Comment: And what is a point of having coefficients in  $\Bbb{Q}(i)$ and not $\Bbb{Q}$?

Comment: @JCAA $\Bbb{Q}(i)$ is dense and of zero measure in $\Bbb{C}$, and it's also a field.

Comment: If you change the set of coefficients to rationals, you will get different sets of roots? Certainly $\Bbb A$ will be the same.

Comment: @JCAA That's what I'm worried about. I don't know any way to change infinite complex coefficients to reals without changing the series' zeropoints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Claim:**$\;$For all $u\in\Bbb{C}$ there exist $c_0,c_1,c_2,...\in\Bbb{Q}(i)$, not all zero, such that the power series
$$
f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_kz^k
$$
has $u$ as a zero and has infinite radius of convergence.

**Proof:**

Let $u\in\Bbb{C}$.

If $u=0$ we can just take $f(z)=z$.

Next suppose $u\ne 0$.

Let
$$
f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_kz^k
$$
where $c_0,c_1,c_2,...\in\Bbb{Q}(i)$ with $c_0\ne 0$ are chosen in succession so as to satisfy
$$
\left|\,\sum_{k=0}^n c_ku^k\right|
\,<\,
\frac{|u|^{n+1}}{2{\,\cdot\,}(n+1)!}
$$
for all nonnegative integers $n$.

Then by the squeeze theorem, it follows that $f(u)=0$.

To show that $f(z)$ has infinite radius of convergence, it suffices to show that for all integers $n\ge 1$ we have
$$
|c_n| < \frac{b}{n!}
$$
where $b=\max(|u|,1)$.

Fix $n\ge 1$.$\;$Then
\begin{align*}
|c_n|
&=
\frac{|c_nu^n|}{|u|^n}
\\[4pt]
&=
\frac
{
\left|\,
\left(
{\displaystyle{
\sum_{k=0}^n c_ku^k
}}
\right)
-
{\displaystyle{
\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} c_ku^k\right)
}}
\right|
}
{|u|^n}
\\[4pt]
&\le
\frac
{
\left|\,
{\displaystyle{
\sum_{k=0}^n c_ku^k
}}
\right|
+
\left|\,
{\displaystyle{
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} c_ku^k
}}
\right|
}
{|u|^n}
\\[4pt]
&=
\frac
{
\left|\,
{\displaystyle{
\sum_{k=0}^n c_ku^k
}}
\right|
}
{|u|^n}
+
\frac
{
\left|\,
{\displaystyle{
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} c_ku^k
}}
\right|
}
{|u|^n}
\\[4pt]
&<
\frac
{
\left(
{\Large{
\frac{|u|^{n+1}}{2{\,\cdot\,}(n+1)!}
}}
\right)
}
{|u|^n}
+
\frac
{
\left(
{\Large{
\frac{|u|^n}{2{\,\cdot\,}n!}
}}
\right)
}
{|u|^n}
\\[4pt]
&=
\frac{|u|}{2{\,\cdot\,}(n+1)!}
+
\frac{1}{2{\,\cdot\,}n!}
\\[4pt]
&\le
\frac{b}{2{\,\cdot\,}(n+1)!}
+
\frac{b}{2{\,\cdot\,}n!}
\\[4pt]
&<
\frac{b}{2{\,\cdot\,}n!}
+
\frac{b}{2{\,\cdot\,}n!}
\\[4pt]
&=
\frac{b}{n!}
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
which completes the proof.